# Why is this pronoun indirect?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, constructions-causatives

Je ne comprends pas le sens de *leur fait* dans la phrase suivante :

> Ils ont été inculpés de "piraterie en groupe organisé", ce qui leur fait encourir jusqu'à 15 ans de prison.

Answer (score 3):

Je vais essayer d'expliquer autrement par une progression pas à pas.

Ce crime fait encourir jusqu'à vingt ans de prison.

On a commis ce crime,  ce qui fait encourir à l'auteur (ou aux auteurs) jusqu'à vingt ans de prison.

"Ils ont commis ce crime [*évidemment pluriel, puisqu'il y a ici la circonstance aggravante de bande organisée*], ce qui fait (donc) encourir (à eux) jusqu'à vingt ans de prison.

Pour être juridiquement correct - nul n'a le droit d'affirmer "ils ont commis" avant qu'un tribunal n'ait prononcé une condamnation, l'inculpation n'est qu'une mesure d'instruction, appelée d'ailleurs maintenant mise en examen, car elle passait dans l'esprit du public pour une pré-condamnation - puis également grammaticalement correct, cela devient :

"ils ont été mis en examen pour ce crime, ce qui leur fait encourir jusqu'à vingt ans de prison.

Comment: Merci.  Je pense que je comprends maintenant.  Cette  proposition est un exemple du causatif et "à eux" c'est l'agent ?  En anglais, on peut le traduire (certes de manière indirecte): "which [crime] causes up to 15 years in prison to be incurred by them"

Comment: Non, un agent est celui qui agit ; le "à eux" (évidemment "leur" en français, je ne l'avais mis que pour expliquer la démarche) est un complément. La traduction anglaise est erronée, du moins très lourde : incur = suffer (à peu près) ; il faut dire : "They are liable to 20 years of imprisonnment".

Comment: I hope you will excuse me if I switch to English because I am still confused and continuing this in French is only making me more confused.  I understand the sense of the sentence.  My translation was an attempt at a literal translation of what I thought was happening grammatically in the sentence.  I thought it was something like the receiver + agent construction, seen in the following:   http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/how-to-properly-utilize-the-causative-have-in-french  If not, what does the à belong to?  I guess my question ultimately is why is the pronoun indirect?

Comment: I answered in French, believing you would be more at ease. I read three times your link, and don't make much sense of it - despite approbations from others - (I have added a comment).

Comment: (Following - I was interrupted) "Je fais laver la voiture à Michel" is impossible, except if you understand "à" as very familiar variant for "de", used only by illiterate people. In "Je fais manger Michel", of course the agent is "Je", and Michel the complement.

Comment: With all due respect, I have to differ as I have subsequently found this causatif construction in several of my grammar textbooks.  Perhaps this will clarify the issue? http://www.library.csi.cuny.edu/~talarico/frenchgrammar/french313/infinitves.pdf

Answer (score 3):

"*ce qui leur fait encourir*" = "*ce qui fait encourir à eux*"

Cependant "*ce qui fait encourir à eux*" n'est pas une construction correcte en français c'est pourquoi on utilise "*ce qui leur fait encourir*".

Comment: Bien sûr ! C'était pour expliquer la construction, et je précise immédiatement qu'il faut remettre ça en ordre, juridiquement et grammaricalement.

Comment: @MarkThorin Je doute que cette réponse visait la vôtre... Celle-ci est simplement similaire.

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette phrase, tu peux remplacer *ce qui leur fait encourir* par *ils risquent* :

> Ils ont été inculpés de "piraterie en groupe organisé", ils risquent jusqu'à 15 ans de prison.

Cela simplifie la phrase.

En fait, il faut considérer *faire encourir* comme un verbe à part entière. On utilise *fait* dans la phrase pour signifier qu'ils encourent des années de prison parce qu'ils ont mal agis. C'est "ce qui va être fait à eux".

On aurait aussi pu tout simplement écrire :

> Ils ont été inculpés de "piraterie en groupe organisé" ; ils encourent donc jusqu'à 15 ans de prison.

Comment: Merci.  Je pense que j'ai posé peut-être la mauvaise question.  Ce que je trouve difficile  à comprendre c'est "leur fait encourir".  Cela veut dire "ce qui fait à eux"?  Je connais la construction "faire qch à qqn"  et en effet je comprends le sens général de cette phrase mais je ne comprends pas comment cette construction est utilisée dans cette phrase.

Comment: @Claudie: c'est bien cette construction qui est utilisée. « Leur inculpation » fait « encourir jusqu'à 15 ans de prison » à « eux ».

Comment: J'ai édité ma réponse pour expliquer le sens de _faire encourir_.

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être sera-ce plus clair ainsi ?

ce qui fait (que) = d'où il s'ensuit (que) = ce dont il résulte (que)

Il aurait été plus élégant d'écrire :

..., et sont donc passibles de ...

Comment: « Ce qui fait qu'ils encourent » et « ce qui leur fait encourir » ce n'est pas la même construction grammaticale. Je suis d'accord que dans ce cas le sens reste presque identique, mais cette réponse n'aide pas à comprendre comment la phrase est construite (et cela me semble être l'origine du problème).