# Laisser faire quelque chose à quelqu'un

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

D'après Grevisse:

> Quand l'impératif d'un des verbes voir, entendre, écouter, etc., régit un infinitif, le pronom personnel objet de cet impératif (et en même temps sujet de l'infinitif) se met à l'accusatif (forme du COD) si l'infinitif est un verbe intransitif ou transitif indirect:
>
> > Ne les laissez pas partir.
> > Ne la faites pas venir.
> > Ne la laissez pas nuire à sa famille.
>
> Il se met, soit à l'accusatif, soit au datif (forme du COI) si l'infinitif est un verbe transitif direct: Ne les laissez pas lire ce livre, ne leur laissez pas lire ce livre.

Alors si nous supposons qu'Albert donne de l'argent à Jean et que je le laisse faire ça, laquelle des deux phrases suivantes est correcte?

1. *J'ai laissé donner de l'argent à Albert; je lui ai laissé donner de l'argent.* (Albert donne l'argent.)
2. *J'ai laissé donner de l'argent à Jean (par Albert); je lui ai laissé donner de l'argent (par Albert).* (Jean obtient l'argent d'Albert.)

Comment: on dirait plutot **J'ai laissé Albert donner de l'argent** (à Jean)

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6858/how-to-properly-utilize-the-causative-have-in-french

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Pourriez-vous me faire, comme réponse ou dans un commentaire, une comparaison entre _laisser_ et _faire_ s'il vous plaît? Merci d'avance!

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il semble y avoir une différence pour la montée des clitiques entre ces deux constructions : *Je la lui fait laver, la voiture* vs *Je l'ai laissé lui donner de l'argent*. Dans un cas, on a les deux pronoms sur le premier verbe, dans l'autre un pronom sur chaque verbe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alors si on suppose qu'Albert donne de l'argent à Jean et que JE le laisse faire, les phrases suivantes seraient correctes et minimalement ambiguës :

1. Je l'ai laissé donner de l'argent à Jean.
2. J'ai laissé Albert lui donner de l'argent.
3. Je l'ai laissé lui donner de l'argent.

La solution proposée avec un seul clitique LUI serait effectivement ambiguë et le pronom pourrait référer à l'un des deux participants sans que son rôle soit clair.

Comment: Mais il est aussi correcte de dire: _J'ai laissé couper les cheveux à ma fille par ma femme_ que _J'ai laissé ma femme couper les cheveux à ma fille_, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @MohammadSanei *Je l'ai laissée lui couper les cheveux* est la forme courte des phrases modifiées comme recommandé par cl-r.

Comment: @cl-r Pourquoi dans mon dictionnaire (Hachette) c'est couper les cheveux **à** qn?

Comment: @GAMPUB et à Mohammad : Depuis que je suis tout petit on me dit : "On coupe les cheveux *de* quelqu'un" ... or vous avez raison, la formulation correcte est avec **à** ; j'ai donc supprimé mon commentaire. Pourtant "Tu es en train de couper les cheveux *de* Jean" me semble plus audible qu'avec *à*, car les cheveux appartiennent à Jean, mais la grammaire à ses secrets qu'il faut sans cesse découvrir. Une rapide recherche sur le Net indique que l'oral utilise facilement *de*, comme on peigne les cheveux de quelqu'un....

Comment: ... suite ... j'ai posé la question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/couper-les-cheveux-%C3%A0-quelquun-est-correct-pourtant-de-est-usit%C3%A9 pour en avoir le cœur net. :)

Comment: @cl-r S'il s'agit de couper les cheveux de Jean, tout va bien, mais le coiffeur va sans doute faire une coupe à Jean.

Comment: @GAMPUB Mais je viens de découvrir "qu'il s'agit de couper les cheveux *a* Jean" !... le *de* n'est pas académique, donc TOUT va mal ! Pour la coupe, c'est le verbe *faire* : on fait qqch à qqn, donc cela ne m'interpelle pas.

Comment: @cl-r On a aussi coupé la tête à Louis XVI...

Comment: @GAMPUB C'est moins choquant,  il aurait put couper la *tête à* toto (facilité par la suppression du *e* : latétatoto, facile à dire, quasi impossible avec le *de* :  latétEUdEUtoto) sans que cela agace mon oreille.

Comment: @MohammadSanei Votre dictionnaire utilise une expression familière, et pas tout à fait correcte car couper des cheveux n'est pas une expression figurée (Cf : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14489/couper-les-cheveux-%C3%A0-quelquun-est-correct-pourtant-de-est-usit%C3%A9 )