# Couper les cheveux à quelqu'un est correct, pourtant de est usité

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prépositions

Il est correct de dire :

> J'ai coupé les cheveux **à** ma fille.

Or l'on entend, et on lit sur le Net

> J'ai coupé les cheveux **de** ma fille.

... et cela ne me choque pas car :

> J'ai peigné les cheveux *de* ma fille avant de les couper.
>
> C'est à ma fille, c'est la poupée *de* ma fille.

J'associe *être à* quelqu'un, mais *être l'objet de* quelqu'un.

À moins que ce soit une spécificité de l'utilisation de *couper quelque chose à quelqu'un*, quels sont les raisonnements qui entrent en conflit avec l'oral et un certain nombre d'usages ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas le sentiment que _à_ soit ici utilisé pour exprimer un possessif, mais plutôt le « récipiendaire » du service : « J'ai rendu service _à_ mon ami. » Dans un cas, on se concentre sur la personne à qui l'on rend service, dans l'autre sur la personne à qui appartiennent les cheveux. C'est ainsi que je comprends ces phrases. À creuser, sans doute.

Comment: *Pourquoi pourrait-on préférer dire "je lui coupe les cheveux" à "je coupe ses cheveux"* : cas 1 : je coupe les cheveux d'un(e) client(e) - cas 2 : je coupe les cheveux d'une personne à qui je porte **une attention particulière** ; la grammaire est ici une lorgnette qui oblitère les nuances de la langue. "Les chevals ils ont courri beaucoup vite" est une phrase parfaitement correcte (car construite logiquement sans tenir compte des exceptions) par un cerveau humain non pollué par l'emprise des classes dominantes qui captent les usages à leur avantage ! :)

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes : le bounty est très ambitieux ! J'ai tendance à considérer l'usage des prépositions en français comme un joyeux bazar fixé par l'usage. Devrait-on dire "de bois" plutôt que "en bois" ? Pourquoi dit-on "dans la Loire" mais "en Corrèze" ? Et qui sait si le douteux "sur Lyon" ne rentrera pas dans le dictionnaire… (Commentaire probablement hors-sujet)

Comment: @Chop: ça aurait été bien que tu transformes d'une certaine façon ton commentaire en réponse. C'est vraiment la seule explication qui explique l'usage réel. Il suffit de faire quelques recherches sur ngrams pour s'apercevoir que *couper les cheveux à quelqu'un* est utilisé dans des encyclopédies et dictionnaires historiques (tout ce qu'il y a de plus sérieux) qui n'utilisent certainement pas un langage familier. Le sens désignant bien évidement l'action réelle de couper les cheveux. (Ah ok la réponse de LeReferee va dans le même sens c'est vrai.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Puisque vous êtes deux membres respectés (de moi en tout cas) à me le demander, j'ai tenté de rédiger [une réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14539/7224).

Comment: Ce moment, quand un français apprend de nouveaux mots en lisant le titre de la question...

Comment: @styko - Peut-être parce que la rivière *Corrèze* est inclue dans le département éponyme : on parle de la même zone géographique que l'on se réfère à l'une ou l'autre, alors que le mot *Loire* est inclus dans le nom de six départements, le fleuve en traverse nombre d'autres, donne son nom à des 'pays'... Dire *dans la Loire* ne référence pas forcément son département d'origine (si le contexte n'y est pas) mais un fleuve d'environ un millions-et-six-mille mètres.

Comment: @cl-r Je faisais référence à ça (http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043/difficulte). Il semble que le nombre de syllabes est un facteur empiriquement important…

Answer (score 6):

*Préambule*

On m’a toujours appris :

> « On ne dit pas couper les cheveux *à* Jean, mais *de* Jean »,

... or dans le troisième commentaire de *[la réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/laisser-faire-quelque-chose-%C3%A0-quelquun/14487?noredirect=1#comment27680_14487)* :

> @cl-r Pourquoi dans mon dictionnaire (Hachette) c'est : couper les cheveux **à** qn? –  Mohammad Sanei Jul 24 at 13:18

Lors de la consultation de mon dictionnaire favori je trouve « couper la gorge **à** quelqu’un » (dans le sens diviser avec un instrument tranchant), « Elle s’est fait couper **les** cheveux chez son coiffeur », « Couper quelque chose **dans** un discours », tombe ensuite sur « TRANS. IND. – FAM. Couper à ⇒ éviter : « couper **à** une corvée, y échapper » et lit d’autres acceptions du verbe.

La question est donc posée au lecteur de French Language ([pas] toujours bêta<sup>1</sup>) pour obtenir des éclaircissements.

Peu après avoir posé la question je trouve une réponse dans le *[dictionnaire de l'Académie française,](http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm)*, elle n'était pas mentionnée à première vue dans les recherches antérieures et remet à sa place ce qui a toujours été pris pour une ‘vérité véritablement vraie, valable, véridique, vérifiée’<sup>2</sup> :

- *Couper qqch **à** qqn est rangé dans le paragraphe **figuratif et familier*** :

Les expressions familières n'entraient pas dans les enseignements de l'école (qui à l’époque n’imaginait même pas que la grammaire puisse devenir moderne et jargonnante), elles devaient (et donc elles doivent toujours) être corrigées.

Cette réponse est donc postée, les commentaires ont aidés à son amélioration puis ont été supprimés,quand soudain une aguichante barre chocolatée<sup>3</sup> de haute valeur vient encore tout chambouler. Pour un non grammairien uniquement francophone le coup est rude, mais nous en reparlerons à la fin, donc voici la réponse académique (certain la qualifie de sémantique) reformulée et amendée :

---

*Usage des prépositions :

Expression figurative ou familière : **a***, versus, *Expression de la réalité : **de***

Dictionnaire de l’Académie française :

> ***Expr. fig. et fam.*** :
>
> - Couper les ailes *à* quelqu'un.

Mais « On a coupé la tête *à* Louis XVI » bien que cela ne soit pas figuratif devient donc familier, car il est plus facile de prononcer la *tête **à** toto*, que *la tête **de** toto*, car aucun *e* ne peut être élidé ce qui oblige à prononcer une syllabe de plus.

Or lorsque l'on raccourcit la chevelure de quelqu'un on en retranche, pour de vrai, une partie :

> ***3. Ôter, retrancher une partie d'un ensemble ; séparer*** :

> - Couper un pan *de* montagne pour construire une route ; (pour un objet).
> - La guerre l'avait durant quatre ans coupé *de* sa famille ; (pour un humain).

En plus la forme pronominale utilise *de*, (qu'il s'agisse de personne ou d'objet) ce qui accoutume l'oreille au *de* !

> ***Pron.***

> - Se couper *de quelqu'un*, le perdre de vue, cesser toute relation avec lui.
> - Se couper *de quelque chose*, perdre le contact avec elle.

Une recherche sur *[CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/couper)*, fournit l’étymologie :
 XIe siècle. Dérivé de coup. Au sens propre « diviser d'un coup », d'où « *couper* ».

Il utilise *de*, parfois *dans* : « Couper un passage *dans* un livre » (j'aurais tendance à lire : « il a physiquement découpé les pages *du* livre où se trouvait le passage abhorré » et à dire : « Il a coupé un passage *du* livre ») :

> ***☆3. Ôter, retrancher une partie d'un ensemble ; séparer.*** Couper un pan de montagne pour construire une route. (Reprise de la citation de l’Académie française)

En revanche il supprime la préposition dans une *expression figurative* :

> Couper *les* angles, les arrondir ; *fig.*, trouver des compromis.

Il rattache aussi *à* aux locutions familières :

> ***☆3. Loc. fam.*** *Couper à*, échapper à quelque chose de déplaisant, l'éviter. Il a l'art de couper *à* toutes les corvées. Vous ne couperez pas *à* une punition.

Dans les *expressions populaires*, les prépositions ne sont pas les mêmes, pourtant le *de* revient une fois :
*Ne pas y couper de.* : Vous n'y couperez pas *d'une* amende, *d'une* contravention.
*Couper dans*, se laisser prendre, se laisser tromper par quelque chose, y croire naïvement. Il coupe *dans* tous les boniments.

Une recherche sur Porter, suggérée par un commentaire :

> ***[PORTER](http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm) § A 2***. Tenir, avoir sur soi : ... *Porter* le deuil *de* quelqu'un, le nom *de* Tibert...

Je n'ai pas trouvé d’exemple avec *à* dans cet alinéa,  et on retrouve dans le figuratif :

> ***$ B 2. figuratif*** : Porter à croire, ...

---

*Commentaire sur la question :*

Ce ne me semble pas être une question de grammaire, mais de *réalité ou non*, avec aussi des exceptions (*dans, les*) qui tendent à montrer que l'emploi des prépositions est hérité de l'usage plus que d'un concept grammatical :

- 1°) Si cela existe *on utilise* **de**,

Si l'on utilise *a* on use d’un langage familier : 'grammaire' orale, grammaire des sons (pardon des phonèmes), qui associe *qqch **à** qqn*, après tout *à* est l'homonyme de *a*.
Quelquefois, “pour être sûr et certain” que le lien existe (cas du mariage par exemple) *a*(vec) se surajoute : et on marie *qqn **avec** qqn*, et non pas *qqn à qqn* comme il est d'usage.

- 2°) Si cela appartient à l'imagination *on utilise* **à**, si l'on emploie *de* les tournures usuelles sont invalides : On ne peut pas « couper les ailes de quelqu’un » car cela ne peut s’appliquer à l’humain, qui n’en a pas, ni aux anges que l’on ne voit pas (ce serait peut-être envisageable de les couper sur une image les représentant).

Ici la 'grammaire' orale n'est pas concernée, *de* étant déjà réservé aux nobles avec qui l'ont ne doit pas être familier, alors *on* s'en méfie !

---

*Commentaire sur le bounty :*

Je rends hommage à Divulgâchâmes d’avoir été interpellé par mes propres interrogations.

Dans cette rencontre nous sommes complémentaires :

–  J’essaie de remonter aux sources, tant étymologiques que celles du langage, là où le cerveau prépare et porte à notre conscience les vibrations sonores en préparation avant même qu’elles ne franchissent définitivement les cordes vocales ; c’est un comportement de francophone sans grammaire (Peut-être suis-je un avatar de M. Jourdain<sup>4</sup>), qui s’intéresse au souffle du verbe dans les arts vivants, aux richesses multiples de la francophonie.

–  Sur cette page, Divulgâchâmes, essaie et investit sans relâche pour qu’on l’aide à trouver des règles et des lois, pour faire entrer des morceaux de phrases dans des cases après les avoir soigneusement identifiés, étiquetés (une forme d’industrialisation du vivant) en recherchant et compilant les écrits, le passé, tous ces mondes morts qui ne revivent que pendant le temps où l’on pense à eux ; c’est un univers de chasseurs où la sérendipité est un cadeau du ciel.

Et si la trouvaille de cette chasse était d’accepter les limites formelles de la grammaire au-delà desquelles il n’y a pas d’explications mentales, où les conjectures se perdent dans la pluralité des définitions aux apparentes contradictions, qu’il y a des zones du français où l’intuition et la créativité bousculent joyeusement les certitudes pour amener un peu de rêve, de poésie, une indécision, du glamour, un sourire… puis une évolution du langage lorsque tout le monde *l’entend* ainsi.

… et parmi les nombreuses questions de la carotte chocolatée, la seule à laquelle je peux essayer répondre :

> la grammaire rejoint-elle la sémantique ?

**Non ET Oui** :

*Non*
Dans l’apprentissage d’une langue, on se heurte à la réalité, au sensible : bambins, les mots ont le sens du concret qui nous entoure, et puis ils s’organisent et par la puissance statisticienne de notre cerveau on conclut que « les chevals ils ont courri beaucoup vite », alors la Grammaire arrive… et on tord le bras aux règles fondamentales, on introduit exceptions, complications, on pinaille… la suite est singulière pour chacun, mais le résultat communément partagé, et bon nombre d’allergie en résulte.

La grammaire ne peut donc pas rejoindre la sémantique, puisque dès le départ elle est ne lui est pas jointe : que l’on soit animal ou humain, chaque son a un sens, exprime quelque chose de ressenti, voire une émotion, un essai de communication, ensuite, le grammairien, comptable tatillon, codifie, impute, regroupe, trie, ordonne, totalise, ergote, redresse, rapproche, vérifie, valide, règle, tranche, certifie, impose, déclare… **♭***mol* : au lieu de chiffrer au centième d’unité les valeurs financières qui dessèche le cœur du comptable<sup>5</sup>, le grammairien utilise des contraintes réglementaires semblables pour faire son *bilan*, son inventaire des mots et de leur agencement que lui seul définit... mais alors que la comptabilité vit du zéro et du un, au vrai ou faux de notre syntacticien s'ajoute autre chose d'indéfinissable, peut-être le doute, l'inconnu, le silence, le troisième infini de la complexité ? Il surchauffe ses neurones pour réduire les expressions de la Vie et les faire entrer dans son monde verbal, qui devient verbeux… hors duquel point de salut ! Il n’y a pas de jeu, de ce jeu que l’on laisse entre deux pièces mobiles pour qu’elles puissent se mouvoir aisément l’une par rapport à l’autre.

La grammaire vient mettre un peu d’ordre pour essayer d’universaliser les rapports humains, c’est donc une contrainte qui s’appuie sur une réalité, elle est seconde par rapport au sens, et elle le rend plus aisé à transmettre.

Quand elle prend le masque des automates correcteurs d'orthographe... comme je l'accueille avec soulagement !

*ET*
Non elle ne peut pas se ‘joindre à nouveau’ à la sémantique, mais elle peut la rejoindre en la rattrapant :

*Oui*
– Dis donc phonème A, j’ai plusieurs façons de t’écrire, avec deux accents possibles, un h avant ou (plusieurs) h après, en majuscule ou minuscule… tu dois mettre *à* après le verbe couper parce que...
– Que nenni dame Grammaire, laissez tomber vos certitudes, « la Justice est la pire façon de gouverner les hommes (Lao Tseu) » et leur langage, acceptez que dans la même forme, selon l’intention, l’intonation, le contexte, *à* soit valable ou pas, qu’il ait un double sens ou qu’il handicape la compréhension : Ah Ah Ah : vous le lisez narquois, vindicatif, dérisoire, sur le même ton, ironique, exclamatif, admiratif… ? Il vous manque (ou plutôt vous les refusez) les vibrations de la vie pour trancher ; à bout de souffle, allez toquer chez de sages académiciens qui conservent les cas d’usage, et, vous rejoindrez la sémantique pour valider vos hypothèses… ce qui ne vous empêchera de mettre en jargon, à vous seul compréhensible, ce que vous pourrez qualifier verbeusement.
Sur ce, dame Grammaire, ne retournez pas au plus haut de votre donjon, vous êtes toujours utile, quoique souvent incompréhensible au commun des francophones.

Il y a donc une part indécidable dans la grammaire, qui n’est qu’une illusion d’ordre : ou elle vit avec les mots et évolue avec eux, ou elle s’enferme dans un conservatoire qui leur est délétère, confirmant une loi de l'entropie : tout système qui tend vers l'immobilisme tend vers la mort.
Pendant ces mouvements, ces évolutions, il y a un espace puis des héritages où elle ne peut rien décider : j’ai toujours entendu dire « Ce sont eux », jusqu’à ce que Georges Marchais impose à tout le monde « C’est eux » aujourd’hui accepté, les deux sont entièrement corrects : soit *eux* désigne un ensemble seul (composé de personnes), soit *ce sont* des personnes regroupées, que peut donc faire la grammaire ici ? Peut-être des périphrases, ce sont elles (c’est elles ??) qui croqueront le bounty.

---

***[Codicille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/codicille)**<sup>6</sup>  pour l’héritage du bounty*

À moins que ce ne soit déjà l’obole pour le Cerbère qui accueillera bientôt ces mots qui partiront vite vers l’oubli, c’est à la déesse Francophonie, jeune déesse du mont Olympe, avatar d’une *[parèdre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/par%C3%20%A8dre)* de l’ancestral [*mont Meru](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meru)*  que je dédie cette récompense.

En effet, *[le livre que Divulgâchâmes interroge](https://books.google.com/books?id=mVn11LzFt_wC&lpg=PA111&ots=pU5ns7nvBD&dq=%22compl%C3%A9ment%20de%20relation%22&pg=PA112#v=onepage&q=%22compl%C3%A9ment%20de%20relation%22&f=false)* (et de ce fait qui l’interroge en retour)  peut être lu par un grammairien pour répondre à des questions intellectuelles de haut niveau, ou par un néophyte pour les exemples.
C’est donc l’élégance du geste de Divulgâchâmes qui offre une lecture du français sous des angles différents.

C’est ainsi que les langues s’apprennent : des citations, des tournures, des exemples que l’on mémorise, que l’on rapproche, que l’on relie à ceux de sa langue maternelle, et puis que l’on peut approfondir en en comprenant l’architecture syntaxique, alors on peut affiner la grammaire… ou pas ; dans le cas de la question originelle de cette page on choisit sa réponse en fonction de ce que l’on veut exprimer.

Les règles ne sont pas des lois, puisqu’on les prouve par leur exceptions.
S'il y a une loi, peut-elle être autre que :

- L’utilisation des prépositions est soumise à l’usage.
- Lorsque le choix est multiple, l’intention de l’auteur décide.

Si mes maîtres et maîtresses d’école, disciples de ceux de la IIIe République m’ont inculqué quelques notions de français, c’est qu’ils devaient sans doute savoir jouer sur ces deux tableaux et contrôler l’un par l’autre, et surtout s’assurer de la correction des termes employés tant du côté grammaire que du côté des dictionnaires, pour définir la correction des usages.

En pratique beaucoup connaissent les exemples et les usages, ont un peu lu, bien peu connaissent le jargon des grammairiens, et je suis dans les rangs de ces derniers.

Changer de point de vue n’est pas changer de siège au cinéma, c’est tantôt regarder et analyser des images tantôt observer comment la lumière et les Ténèbres en mouvement écrivent ; qui peut dire que l’un est préférable à l’autre ? Bienvenue en Francophonie.

*Post Scriptum Codicillaire :*
À l’expression Québéco-européenne ultra majoritaire de ce site, qu’il serait bon d’accueillir les francophones d’Afrique, des Océans et de milles autres endroits riches d'usages et d’expressions savoureuses pour appeler ce site **French Language & Francophonie**, ce ne serait pas tautologique : on étudie une langue à l’école & on la vit ‘plongé’ dedans quel que soit la longitude et la latitude ; là encore, deux points de vue qui au fond n’en font qu’un pour celles et ceux qui veulent la découvrir y trouver des points de repère complémentaires... Mais cela va être peut-être être discuté sur *[FE_meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/french-language-francophonie)*

---

*<sup>Pour les non francophones :</sup>*

<sup>A - Pour accéder à la recherche de mot 

. Bouton Dictionnaire sans menu déroulant

. Menu principal

. Lancer une recherche dans le dictionnaire

. Première case : couper

. et accéder au paragraphe (4)COUPER 

1 – *bêta*  est la deuxième lettre de l’alphabet grec – une notation mathématique ou technique – une phase d’avancement de projet – mais aussi : une personne *bête, niaise, stupide*.

2 – Exemple de pléonasmes multiples à ne mettre qu’entre guillemets à l’écrit ; pourrait-on alors parler de pléonasmes tautologiques, ou de pléonasme de puissance tautologique ? Ou l’inverse tautologies pléonastissime ? Ouvrir une question sur FLβ est-il nécessaire ? Grammaticalement nuls, peuvent-ils être entendus comme une forme (désuète, incisive, obsolète, nécessaire… ?) d’humour (figuratif, familier, réel, objectif…) ? De poésie 'Oulipesque' ? Qui sait ?

3 – ‘Bounty’ est devenu le nom commercial d’une confiserie… pas vraiment diététique.

4 – Personnage de Molière qui découvre qu’il s’exprimait en prose sans le savoir.

5 - La phrase exacte entendue de la bouche d’un expert comptable. : « La comptabilité dessèche les cœurs. »

6 – Se prononce [kɔdisil].</sup>

Comment: Eh, il manque *syntagme* ! Blague à part, très bonne réponse très approfondie, de celles qui font l'intérêt des bountys (orthographe 1990…).

Comment: @styko Eh... non ! J'ai été obligé de relire la définition du mot qui subordonnait ma réponse à la grammaire, alors que cela débute par *duo* ou *couple* qui sont si parlant... et vivants, ils circulent de bouches à oreilles, les yeux fermés; puis trio, quartuor ou autres sextet musicaux.. alors on évaluerait les relations d'un mot : il possède un (petit) groupe, une tribu, une foule : la relativité de M. Einstein deviendrait lumineuse, évidente : l'énergie d'un mot est égal à sa quantité de relations possibles que l'ont peut constamment retrouver dans les vibrations sonores des cordes vocales

Comment: Tu écris « couper **les** cheveux », « pan *de* montagne » et « couper *les* angles », comme si tu espérais trouver une préposition qui a une quelconque importance. Ces occurrences n'ont absolument rien à voir avec la question (*les* n'est d'ailleurs même pas une préposition).

Comment: Peux-tu donner un lien qui fonctionne pour « Couper qqch à qqn est figuratif et familier » que tu attribues à l'Académie française. Je ne trouve cet extrait ni dans la 8e ni dans la 9e édition. J'ai bien peur que tu ne le sortes du contexte, voire même que ta citation soit inexacte. *Couper les cheveux* c'est différent de *Couper le sifflet, les ailes ou les jambes à quelqu'un*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Le lien ne fonctionne pas par couper/coller à cause des `;`, j'ai donc mis dans les notes en bas de page la marche à suivre pour lancer une recherche.  En effet ce n'est pas un extrait de Academie9, celui-ci se trouve avec  les premiers mots en gras **Expr. fig. et fam. :**  au début du corps de la réponse (c'est un copier/coller). J'ai corrigé le format de la présentation pour qu'il n'y ait plus de confusion.

Comment: Il m'est plus difficile de répondre aux remarques que tu as relevé et qui ne corroborent pas ton point de vue sur le choix des exemples. En fait j'ai pris celui d'un non francophone qui analyse une référence lexicale. Les notions grammairiennes n'y figurent pas, pourtant il y une autre source de compréhension sous-jacente, à la fois logique, intuitive ET contrôlable. Que ce soit en primaire ou avec le Gaffiot, je suis toujours reparti des exemples pour retrouver les règles... c'était avant les chamboulements de la nouvelle grammaire ! ....…

Comment: Franchement c'est la réponse la plus longue que j'ai jamais vu sur SE. Très bien expliqué, +1 à votre question et +1 à la réponse :)

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais que ça dépend de ce sur quoi on veut mettre l'accent.

### Premier cas :

> J'ai coupé les cheveux de ma fille

L'accent est mis sur le fait que ce sont "les cheveux de ma fille", et que c'est cet ensemble que j'ai coupé. La phrase de décompose ainsi :

> J'ai coupé - les cheveux de ma fille

- Couper : verbe transitif direct
- Les cheveux de ma fille : COD

### Second cas :

> J'ai coupé les cheveux à ma fille

L'accent dans ce second cas est mis sur le fait qu'on exerce une action sur une personne. Par exemple, "À qui ai-je coupé les cheveux". La phrase de décompose ainsi :

> J'ai coupé les cheveux - à ma fille

- Couper les cheveux : action, groupe verbal transitif indirect
- À ma fille : COI

Comment: Cela n'explique pas le "choix d'utilisation" de l'Académie française [ (de)  propre | (à) figuré et/ou familier ] qui en indique le bons usage : dans votre premier cas vous être conforme à la langue soutenue, dans le second vous vous exprimez familièrement, et cela ne saurait être toléré dans un écrit soutenu qu'entre guillemets pour rapporter une conversation.

Comment: On peut dire ''J ai coupé les cheveux à Jean" comme on peut dire ''J'ai acheté un cadeau à ma mère". Et dans ce cas, ce n'est pas familier. Car c'est à Jean que j'ai coupé les cheveux et à personne d'autre tout comme  c 'est à ma mère que j'ai acheté un cadeau et à personne d'autre. Ce qui est familier c'est de remplacer ''de" par ''à" quand il s'agit d'un complément de nom exprimant une possession. ''Le sac à ma soeur est en faux cuir" est incorrect. Il faut dire ''Le sac de ma soeur est en faux cuir".

Comment: @cl-r : Je pense que l'avantage de la tournure : "J'ai coupé les cheveux *de* ma fille" est qu'il n'y a pas d’ambiguïté, elle est compréhensible de tous et évite à l'interlocuteur qui entendrait cette phrase de croire qu'il a été dit "les cheveux à ma fille", qui est une tournure fausse.

Comment: @Iside Votre raisonnement me gêne. « J'ai acheté un cadeau » est une phrase qui a un sens, et si quelqu'un vous demande la destination, vous pouvez répondre « à ma mère » / « pour ma mère ». En revanche, « j'ai coupé *les* cheveux » est assez douteux (« des cheveux » serait correct), et dire que vous l'avez fait « à destination de Jean » l'est tout autant. C'est de Jean dont vous avez coupé les cheveux, ou à la rigueur c'est à Jean que vous avez coupé des cheveux.

Comment: @cl-r: il me semble que ton interprétation de l'avis de l'Académie est simplement fausse. La construction est tout à fait normale et est utilisée dans des contextes formels.

Answer (score 3):

## Pour reprendre la question

« Couper les cheveux de quelqu'un » serait utilisé mais la version correcte serait « couper les cheveux à quelqu'un ».

## Mon analyse

Ces deux phrases ne sont pas équivalentes, ainsi que le mettent en évidence les formes réduites proposées par [cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/cl-r).

#### Avec « de »

> Je coupe les cheveux de ma fille.
>   Je coupe ses cheveux.

On se concentre ici sur la personne à qui appartiennent les cheveux.

#### Avec « à »

> Je coupe les cheveux à ma fille.
>   Je lui coupe les cheveux.

Ici, c'est le bénéficiaire, la personne à qui l'on rend service, qui est le centre d'attention.

*À* est parfois utilisé — à tort — pour exprimer un possessif mais ce n'est pas le cas dans la structure correcte de cette phrase.

## Discussion

D'après [Stéphane Gimenez♦](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%C3%A9phane-gimenez) :

> Il suffit de faire quelques recherche sur ngrams pour s'apercevoir que couper les cheveux à quelqu'un est utilisé dans des encyclopédies et dictionnaires historiques (tout ce qu'il y a de plus sérieux) qui n'utilisent certainement pas un langage familier.

Sans considérer que cela soit une preuve en soi, un [ngrams basique](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couper+les+cheveux+%C3%A0%2Ccouper+les+cheveux+de&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccouper%20les%20cheveux%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcouper%20les%20cheveux%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCouper%20les%20cheveux%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouper%20les%20cheveux%20de%3B%2Cc0) montre que « à » est globalement plus utilisé que « de », mais l'écart est restreint depuis le XIXème siècle.

Doit-on préférer une forme à l'autre ? *À* semble préféré historiquement mais aucune des deux formes ne me choquent. Elles ne mettent pas l'accent sur la même chose et ont donc selon moi toutes deux leur place afin de participer à la richesse de la communication.

Comment: Il y a quelque chose qui n’est pas harmonieux dans votre réponse, et j’ai su pourquoi lorsque j’ai ajouté un codicille à la mienne. Si l’on prend à la lettre le mot récipiendaire , une coupe de cheveux n’est pas un diplôme, et la fillette ne reçoit rien puisque on lui retire une partie d’elle. Et choisir *destinataire*, que reçoit-elle vraiment ?

Comment: @cl-r Oui, le mot « récipiendaire » me dérangeait aussi mais je ne trouvais pas mieux au moment de l'écriture. Je pense maintenant que « bénéficiaire » du service sonne mieux. Merci pour le commentaire.

Comment: Seriez-vous intéressé par la discussion http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/584/french-language-francophonie ?

Answer (score 2):

Je suis loin d'être un spécialiste, et ma contribution recoupe certaines idées des précédentes. Elle se veut tout de fois plus « intuitive » que spécialiste (ce qui peut poser problème car je ne prends pas toujours le temps de justifier mes phrases).

Mon avis est qu'il n'y a rien de particulier au verbe *couper*, que *de* est très souvent la meilleure tournure et que *à* est souvent familier ou argotique.

En ce qui concerne l'expression de la possession, il n'y a aucun doute. ([Lien](http://bescherelletamere.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/CHATON_9.png) si vous avez de l'humour). Plus sérieusement [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A0/5/difficulte) écrit

> La construction du complément de nom avec à, fréquente dans la langue populaire (la femme au boulanger, la voiture à Jacques, le chat à Margot), est à éviter dans l'expression soignée.
>
> La construction avec à est admise dans les expressions toutes faites comme une bête à bon Dieu, un fils à papa, etc.
>
> (et plein d'autres choses)

Je vous conseille au passage les pages *difficultés* du Larousse en ligne qui sont une vraie mine d'or. Si vous lisez la page en entier, vous comprendrez le bazar que sont les prépositions en français (regardez aussi [de](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/de/21718/difficulte) et [en](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29043/difficulte))

---

Je pense que la plupart des phrases suivent donc, en langue correcte, le schéma de

> Réparer la voiture de quelqu'un

D'ailleurs si le verbe couper venait à se rapporter à autre chose qu'une partie du corps, il n'y aurait pas vraiment de doute

> Couper les fleurs de quelqu'un

Mais pour couper les cheveux ou les ongles, la langue orale hésite… Voyons ce qu'il en est pour d'autres parties du corps

> Opérer le genoux de quelqu'un
>
> Masser les pieds de quelqu'un
>
> Caresser la joue de quelqu'un
>
> Peigner les cheveux de quelqu'un *(moins d'hésitation que pour couper)*
>
> Limer les ongles de quelqu'un *(moins d'hésitation que pour couper)*

Commentez si vous trouvez que certaines de ces tournures sont acceptables avec *à*.

Donc, en langue correcte, il me semble que l'on devrait dire *de* dans tous les **cas concrets** (et *couper* ne semble pas couper à cette règle), même si l'usage oral a tendance à employer *à* dans certains cas. Donc, à part à l'oral si l'on est un peu laxiste

> Couper les cheveux de quelqu'un

---

En revanche, pour les cas abstraits ou imagés (et souvent familiers), il semble que *à* s'impose.

> Casser la figure / la gueule à quelqu'un *([ici](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=3308976645;))*
>
> Tordre le cou à quelqu'un ([ici](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=3308976645;))
>
> Voler dans les plumes à / de quelqu'un *(l'usage semble être flottant, cf [ici](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?104;s=3308976645;r=6;nat=;sol=0;))*

Encore une fois, ce n'est qu'une pseudo-démonstration par des exemples tirés de mon expérience et confirmés par les dictionnaires.
N'hésitez donc pas à donner votre avis pour améliorer cette réponse !

Answer (score 1):

(En réfléchissant à la réponse de @LeReferee et aux commentaires de la mienne, je suis parvenu à une explication assez courte qui m'a convincu, je la poste donc à part. Notez que cette explication est très proche de celle de @LeReferee mais qu'elle s'en écarte sur un point important)

Changeons quelque peu l'exemple de départ (simplement pour être plus clairs) et considérons les deux phrases suivantes.

> 1. Le dentiste a arraché des dents à Thibault.
> 2. Le dentiste a arraché les dents de Thibault.

Les deux phrases ont le même sujet, le même groupe verbal mais des compléments différents.

1. Complément d'objet direct : Qu'est-ce que le dentiste à arraché ? Une seule réponse possible : « des dents ». La réponse « des dents à Thibault » n'est pas possible : elle revient à exprimer la possession avec *à*, ce qui on l'a vu est incorrect. Donc, il y a un complément d'objet indirect. À qui le dentiste a-t-il arraché des dents ? Réponse : « à Thibault »
2. Il est impossible de séparer « les dents » de « de Thibault ». Il n'y a donc qu'un complément d'object direct : « les dents de Thibault » composé d'un nom : « dent » dont la possession est indiquée par « de Thibault » (je ne suis pas sûr de la fonction grammaticale…)

Maintenant, que penser de la phrase suivante ?

> La dentiste a arraché les dents à Thibault.

On l'a vu, en langue soutenue, « les dents à Thibault » ne peut pas être un COD. Pourquoi ne pas séparer « les dents » de « à Thibault » ?

Ce qui me gène est que la phrase « Le dentiste a arraché les dents. » est bancale. Mais attention, elle n'est pas bancale parce qu'il manque un COI, cela voudrait dire que le COD *implique* le COI (ce qui à mon sens n'est pas possible). Elle est bancale parce que le COD « les dents » est bancal. D'où, *à mon sens*, l'impossibilité de la phrase « Le dentiste a arraché les dents à Thibault » où « à Thibault » ne saurait être COI.

(Pardonnez ma grammaire si elle est approximative, et corrigez moi ! Si vous êtes compétents pour me traiter d'imbécile, allez-y !)

---

Pour faire écho à un commentaire de @Iside. Imaginez que c'est bientôt Noël. Votre père peut vous dire

> As-tu acheté un cadeau à Maman ?
>
> As-tu acheté le cadeau de Maman ?  *(Un peu familier mais ça passe, non ?)*
>
> As-tu acheté le Grevisse à Maman ?

mais je ne vois pas de justification simple pour « As-tu acheté le cadeau à Maman ? » (le *Cadeau* ?)

Comment: _mais je ne vois pas de justification simple pour « As-tu acheté le cadeau à Maman ? » (le Cadeau ?)_

"Lui as-tu acheté le cadeau ? - À qui ? - À Maman." : On sait ce qu'est le cadeau donc on y réfère implicitement (au cas où ladite "Maman" entendrait ce qui se dit, on évite de le nommer plus proprement), et on met l'accent que c'est elle qui récupère le cadeau.

Comment: Quand au dents de la mère... Ou plutôt du fils, en fait je n'en sais rien :D : 
"Le dentiste - a arraché les dents - à Thibault." C'est bizarre parce qu'on insiste sur le fait que cet idiot de dentiste les a toutes arrachées à Thibault. Mais c'est à lui qu'on a arraché les dents. De mon point de vue, ça tient.