# Ordre des pronoms compléments des verbes transitifs

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots

En lisant une [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16159/7321) de [Stéphane Gimenez](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/79/st%c3%a9phane-gimenez), une énigme me saute aux yeux :
Pourquoi y a-t-il une différence d'ordre dans les phrases suivantes ?
Qu'est-ce que la troisième personne a de si particulier ?

> Elle me fait payer le resto. / Elle **me** le fait payer.
> Elle te fait payer le resto. / Elle **te** le fait payer.
> Elle lui fait payer le resto. / Elle le **lui** fait payer.
> Elle leur fait faire le ménage. / Elle le **leur** fait faire.

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/the-order-of-direct-and-indirect-object-pronouns

Comment: Ce n'est pas particulier à la contruction “faire faire quelque chose”.

Answer (score 4):

Pour les pronoms placés avant le verbe et la négation, la situation est très simple aujourd'hui :

- ils apparaissent dans un ordre fixe
- un seul élément peut apparaître par position
- on ne peut pas combiner un élément de la 3ème et de la 5ème colonne

Le tableau ci-dessous représente les positions de l'analyse classique de [Miller & Sag (1997, p22)](http://www.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/p.monachesi/ESSLLI01/lastmillsag.pdf)

`+------------+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-----+----+
|   SUJET    | NEG | COD/COI |    COD    |   COI    | LOC | DE |
+------------+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-----+----+
| je         | ne  | me      | le/la/les | lui/leur | y   | en |
| tu         |     | te      |           |          |     |    |
| il/elle/on |     | se      |           |          |     |    |
| nous       |     | nous    |           |          |     |    |
| vous       |     | vous    |           |          |     |    |
| ils/elles  |     |         |           |          |     |    |
+------------+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-----+----+`

Answer (score 2):

En fait, c'est la troisième personne du singulier et du pluriel qui ont quelque chose de particulier, parce *me/te/nous/vous* sont toujours les premiers, c'est seulement la troisième personne qui fait l'exception.

- Elle me le fait payer
- Elle te le fait payer
- Elle nous le fait payer
- Elle vous le fait payer

Mais

- Elle le lui fait payer
- Elle le leur fait payer

Comment: En effet, je corrige donc la question. Mais pourquoi cette particularité ?

Comment: Il y doit y avoir une confusion éventuelle quelque part quand *le/la/les* suivent *lui/leur*, et pour l'éviter, l'ordre a changé pour ces pronoms.

Answer (score 2):

Explication simplifiée, pour la forme affirmative :

- Un pronom (COD/COI) se place entre le sujet et le verbe (ou l'auxiliaire conjugué) : *Je le vois*, *Je l'ai vu*.
- Quand il y a plusieurs pronoms, l'ordre est COI COD. Par exemple : *Je te le donne*.
- Avec impossibilité d'avoir certaines associations: *pronom personnel + COI* devient alors *pronom personnel + verbe + COI*. Par exemple : *Je me confie à toi*.
- Avec 2 exceptions spéciales sur l'ordre :

  - *lui/leur* (COI) précèdent juste le verbe (avec l'exception du point suivant). Donc *Je le lui donne*.
  - *y* et *en* sont encore plus prioritaires et précèdent toujours le verbe: *Je lui parle* mais *Je lui en parle.*
  - Il y a également quelques cas *y + en* : *Il y en a*.

Les inversions (négations, et phrases interrogatives) compliquent encore les schémas.

Sur *Études littéraires*, il y a [un très grand nombre d'explications](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/positionnement-pronoms-personnels.php).

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous voulez dire par précéder le verbe ? Tous les pronoms que vous décrivez précèdent le verbe. *la* n'est jamais COI. *lui* et *leur* viennent après *le/la/les*...

Comment: @GAMPUB - merci - erreur (pas de la), et précision: précède juste.

Answer (score 2):

Parce que ce sont peut-être les seuls pronoms personnels qui ne sont pas identiques quand ils sont COD ou COI :
Pour la première personne, on utilise *me* comme pronom transitif comme intransitif, *te* pour la deuxième personne, mais pour la troisième personne, le pronom transitif est *se* alors que le pronom intransitif est *lui*.

De même pour le pluriel, *nous* et *vous* pour les premières et deuxièmes personnes respectivement, mais pour la troisième personne, *se* est le pronom transitif et *leur* le pronom intransitif.
L'ordre syntaxique correct *Elle me le fait payer* et *Elle le lui fait payer* vient peut-être de là.

Après tout, on parle de la langue française, où chaque règle grammaticale admet des exceptions à n'en plus finir.

Comment: pour la troisième personne du singulier, il y a 3 pronoms possibles pour le COD (se/le/la) et ils n'occupent pas la même position et n'entrent pas dans les mêmes combinaisons...

Answer (score 0):

*Essai pour une réponse de situation :*

- Première et deuxième personne (du singulier ou du pluriel) : il s'agit d'une situation de dialogue (même si je discute avec moi-même, deux acteurs seulement sont en jeu).
- Troisième personne : La 'conversation' (l'échange ou la réflexion que j'ai avec moi-même ou avec un autre) ne concerne plus ceux qui parlent mais porte sur un tiers (secondaire par nature [question d'ego, ou plus élégamment de prérogatives, du locuteur]), cela modifie l'ordre des priorités, la façon de raisonner.

***Elle me le*** : c'est *moi* (ou *toi*) qui est le plus important, puisque je *suis* (tu *es*) acteur, c'est à *moi* (ou à *toi*) que cela arrive, et qu'est-ce qui arrive ? *Le* (l'objet de l'attention).

***Elle le lui*** : *le*, l'objet de l'attention, de la discussion, ce qui  est arrivé concerne *qui* ? *Le* (qui est secondaire par rapport au sujet de l'échange, qui n'est pas acteur 'parlant').

---

Intéressé par la naissance des idées, des mots et leur architecture avant qu'ils soient prononcés, autrement dit, comment le cerveau fonctionne, comment l'inconscient se découvre au travers des filtres qu'il utilise, j'essaie de rechercher comment les phonèmes vivent dans l'oralité, et pourquoi ils ne peuvent s'articuler que de certaines façons quand ils reflètent des situations qui n'apparaissent pas en première lecture ; parfois l'intuition devient évidence... d'autres fois non... peut-être que d'autres points de vue compléteront cette essai.

Comment: On ne saura jamais pourquoi ces juges parfaits 'moinssoient' allègrement contre les usages du site, sans justifier leur décision ; alors que l'énoncé des attendus est une nécessité partout ailleurs.