# Pourquoi est-ce inversé dans « Je le lui donne » ?

Tags: grammaire

Remarquez ces phrases :

```
Je le lui donne
Je lui en donne
```

Qui viennent par exemple de, `je donne l'or à Valentin` et `je donne de l'or à Valentin`.

Tandis que :

```
Je te le donne
Je t'en donne
```

`te` et `t'` sont bien avant `le` et `en` tandis que pour `lui`, c'est inversé. Pareil pour :

Je vous le donne
Je vous en donne

Vous avant le et en mais pas après.

Comme expliquez-vous cette incohérence?

Est-ce « ainsi » et à savoir tout comme il y a un S à la deuxième personne du singulier des verbes du premier groupe et pas à la 1re ni à la 2de et c'est simplement à « apprendre » ?

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1758/1109 et https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17128/1109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il ne s'agit pas d'incohérence mais de variété ;  pour une raison quelconque certaines générations passées n'ont pas jugé absolument nécessaire   d'adopter un mode unique de placement (il y a peut-être une question d'euphonie) ; ce dont on peut parler c'est d'un manque d'uniformité, mais cela ne signifie pas un manque de logique. En allemand, une langue dans laquelle l'ordre des mots est plus libre qu'en français il y a plusieurs possibilités de placement d'un pronom, et évidemment il n'est pas question d'incohérence.

Voici une référence qui donne l'essentiel sur la place de ces pronoms : [réf.](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/pronom-place.html) (simplement ignorer le finnois).