# Ordre/choix de pronoms (Via Mala, de John Knittel, Albin Michel, p.469)

Tags: choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots, pronoms-personnels

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> Il ressentait péniblement l'absence de Sylvelie. Où était-elle en ce moment? Attendant, avec sa famille? Elle avait préféré celle-ci à lui. Elle ne semblait plus lui appartenir.

L'ordre/choix des pronoms  « celle-ci » et « lui » ne me semble pas correct. Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait préciser l'usage ?

Il existe une question sur l'ordre des pronoms mais elle ne traite pas le cas du pronom démonstratif ([ordre des pronoms](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16160/17649)).

Comment: "préférer le thé au café" est correct, "préférer sa famille à son ami" aussi (dans la phrase citée, "celle-ci" remplace valablement "sa famille" et "lui" remplace "son ami").

Comment: Au moins maladroit. Mieux: "elle lui avait avait préféré sa famille". "Elle avait préféré celle-ci à lui" ne passe pas du tout. Ca sent la mauvaise traduction.

Comment: J'écrirais: "Où était-elle en ce moment? En train d'attendre, avec sa famille? Elle lui avait préféré sa famille. Elle ne semblait plus lui appartenir." "Famille" est répété, mais dans ce cas, cette répétition n'est pas malheureuse: elle souligne que "sa famille" est maintenant plus importante que "lui". Et "Elle la lui avait préféré" serait possible, mais un peu trop acrobatique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'écrirais: "Où était-elle en ce moment? En train d'attendre, avec sa famille? Elle lui avait préféré sa famille. Elle ne semblait plus lui appartenir." "Famille" est répété, mais dans ce cas, cette répétition n'est pas malheureuse: elle souligne que "sa famille" est maintenant plus importante que "lui". Et "Elle la lui avait préféré" serait possible, mais un peu trop acrobatique.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec cette révision et le fait que la répétition est acceptable, mais j'aurais aimé qu'une explication du manque d'idiomaticité soit aussi fournie. Je perçois ce défaut mais je ne suis pas capable de trouver les principes qui font que l'impression est mauvaise. Je suis aussi d'accord avec l'impression d'incertitude que laisse « Elle la lui avait préféré » ; j'avais pensé à cette possibilité mais ne la trouvais pas  plaisante, bien qu'elle semble parfaitement logique ; là encore, le principe m'échappe, et c'est surtout ça qui importe, le pourquoi.

Comment: La formulation est effectivement maladroite et le  traducteur aurait pu écrire "Elle lui avait préféré celle-ci". Par contre, quand on ne peut pas mettre le "lui" avant le verbe, on dira éventuellement "Elle avait préféré celle-ci à lui qui était parti depuis si longtemps".

Comment: @LPH Pour des francophones qui ont grandi dans la langue et qui l'utilisent tous les jours, les "principes" ne sont pas toujours accessibles. Le témoignage sur l'usage vivant est quand même pertinent.

Comment: @Frank Là n'est pas la question, que certains puissent aller au-delà d'une certain niveau d'information ou non ; ma remarque concerne la question de savoir par exemple s'il existe une logique à la base, ou si au contraire c'est un usage qui repose sur des notions subjectives plus qu'autre chose. Je ne vous fait pas de reproche, et, je n'en sais pas plus que vous moi-même.

Comment: @LPH "c'est surtout ça qui importe, le pourquoi" - parfois, le "pourquoi", c'est simplement l'usage. Par exemple, dans les conjugaisons de certains verbes, bien qu'une forme grammaticale "correcte" existe, il sera préféré en pratique une circonlocution, ou un changement de temps. Impossible de fournir un "pourquoi", si ce n'est que nous n'avons pas d'affinité pour la forme correcte ...

Comment: @Frank Je sais bien cela, c'est contenu dans ma référence à la possible subjectivité du pourquoi d'un usage, mais il est utile, pour moi tout au moins, de considérer un exemple de plus, même si général.